# Can Classloading be saved, add to, restored, over and over?

Tags: java, groovy, classpath

I have a long-lived program that needs to dynamically update the classpath at runtime.

No problem - the classloader is a URLClassLoader and I call the 'addURL' method.  This all works great for one 'update' iteration.

Later on, when the next 'update' arrives, I would like to be able to restore the original classpath, then repeat the process of calling 'addURL' with the updated entries.  Then this process repeats several days/weeks later.   Do I clone the original classLoader?  Is what I'm trying to do possible?  As if anyone can not already tell, I don't do much with classloaders and am quite at a loss.   I am running groovy from a java jar file, so either Java directly or a Groovy solution would work!

**EDIT**

Per question below.  To continue to run correctly, I need to 'flush' the original changes I made to the classpath, else those might be picked up inadvertently after an update.  Plus, I am concerned about having multiple versions of the same jars on the classpath at the same time.  Example: on the first load, I add myJar1, myJar2, and log4j (<- i.e. not one of my jar files), on the next update, I might need to add an updated version of myJar1 and myJar2, plus myJar3, and log4j.   Does that make more sense?

Comment: what is the reason to restore the original classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do I clone a class loader? Normally you do not. You create a child loader instead.

Instead of adding the jars to the original class loader or trying to change it, you need a child classloader, containing the jars you want to change (and the parent should not have them). To add you create a new such childloader. Restore is done basically by the garbage collection of the JVM and then you can do it over and over. But you should work with versioned jars here, since overwriting an existing jar might be not possible (on windows, since the jar is possibly held open) or cause very strange artifacts.

Should your program itself depend on a class from a jar you want to change, then you will need to change your program to not to depend on it - or better give up on the idea.

If for some reason you still want to go the way of cloning and if your loader is really an ordinary URLClassLoader loading only from URLs (this would for exmaple not work on GroovyClassLoader) then you can use reflection to access the field ucp and on that object the field urls, which is a Stack and should contain the information you are looking for. But be warned, in 99% of the cases this is the wrong way

Comment: Sorry, I was out yesterday.  I follow what you say conceptually and that makes perfect sense.  I spent some time on this today.  Basically, I think I need to create my own instance of a class extending URLClassLoader, have it load my classes.  Next, simply let it go out of scope, then re-create it with the updated file set.  If this works, it is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

For reference if anyone else ever needs this, using @blackdrag answer, I created this Java class:

```
public class DynamicClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    public DynamicClassLoader(ClassLoader parent, URL... urls) {
        super(urls, parent);
    }

    public void addURLs(Iterable<URL> urls) {
        for (URL url : urls) {
            addURL(url);
        }
    }

    public void resetThreadContextLoader() {
        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        currentThread.setContextClassLoader(getParent());
    }
}
```

My usage model is from groovy.  Thus, in order to use this all I did was:

```
def myClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader
dynamicLoader?.resetThreadContextLoader()
dynamicLoader = new DynamicClassLoader(myClassLoader)
dynamicLoader.addURLs(myListOfJarURLs)
```

Works perfectly.  All in very simple - my groovy code will re-execute those four lines above repeatedly over time.  If there was a previous dynamicLoader, then the classpath is reset and modified immediately with an updated list of jars.